# Dynamically Created HTML Link in Data Grid Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a data grid and one of the columns is a link to a file. The base URL is a public variable in the codebehind. All is working as expected except the base URL

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="<a target='_blank' href='<%#BaseURL %>{0}'>{0}</a>" />
```

What I am seeing in the page is

```
<a href="<%#BaseURL %>SS82009310X_U_2013_07_05_01_55.mpg" target="_blank">
```

I need the string value of BaseURL (which is something like `http://myserver/myapp/`)

Answer (score 0):

you could use code behind and populate your column like this:
On you .aspx page define the hyperlink column like this:

`<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:HyperLink ID="hypSelect" 
                   runat="server" 
                   ToolTip="Click for more details." 
                   ImageUrl="~/images/icons/your_icon.png" 
                   NavigateUrl=''>More details</asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>`

And then in your code behind, define an OnRowDataBound event and do this:

`public void gvPAR_RowDataBound(Object Sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink hypSelect = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hypSelect");
        hypSelect.NavigateUrl = "your string url here or call a helper method";
    }
}`

I hope this helps...